# Android [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS] for two different apps

Tags: android

I have two different app (with different package names), but when one is installed, I'm unable to install other and get from **`adb`** `[INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]` error. Is there any solution? I don't understand why it happens.

Thanks

Comment: Apparently, they actually do have the same application ID. That can be set in the module's `build.gradle` file of an Android Studio project. It defaults to the `package` attribute in the root `<manifest>` element of your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: show your AndroidManifest.xml of both apps

Comment: It just decompiler the app and yes, it has different package name then I set into AndroidManifest.xml in AndroidStudio. So I changed and it works! Thanks